# sanity checking package for gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, libtool, binutils

i'm building a cross compiler for my MinGW, targeting i386-pc-linux-gnu. well, i'm concerned with the binutils and gcc (binaries, includes, everything) that i've compiled, being mashed together with the current one.

also, once i get the cross-compile configurations just right, i will be using third party, proprietary c compilers, make, awk, m4, etc, not bundled with the GNU system, to build the cross compiler again, using the same configurations (the one mentioned in above paragraph is just a test). not knowing if this can even succeed, i want to do a a sanity check on the TO BE built and installed gcc; to know if they even produced binaries that can run. i also have to check that this build, just as in the previous paragraph, didn't mash together with the rest of MinGW.

is there a package out there to test gcc?? that it complies with the current version specifications?

Comment: i mean, there's gotta be. you have GNU libtools having all these ways to check what's present in the compiler and other system commands... somebody should've already come up with something to test compliance...

Comment: Just curious, what is your build tuple?  It looks like you are attempting to target a Linux system running on standard hardware, albeit slightly older given that the processor is i386.

Comment: i'm going to be using this to build a kernel and the barebones library/modules for a linux install to my reasonably new PC. i've targeted i386 as i thought that it would be forward compatible with all x86 machines running on linux. but in retrospect i probably should've chosen i786, as it would be used exclusively for building my linux OS.

Comment: If you are installing Linux, why not use one of the many distro's out there?  If you are dead-set on a DIY installation of Linux I'd recommend checking out [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) and [Beyond Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Test suites are part of the gcc project.

See under testsuite here: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/test.html

Also here: https://gcc.gnu.org/testing/

And here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Testsuites.html

And from the above, for cross compilation: https://gcc.gnu.org/simtest-howto.html

Comment: While the test suits are part of gcc, I'm not sure that they will be of much use to the OP.  It is likely, given that he is building a cross-compiler, that any executable compiled on the host system (given that the cross-compiler is targeting another system) will not run on the host system.

Comment: Added the gcc recommended link for testing cross compilation